# n-th: как написать/произнести?

Tags: прилагательные, математика

If I want to write the word "n-th" (as in n-th solution, n-th derivative,...), is it more conventional to write `n-ый/n-ая/n-ое` or `n-й/n-я/n-е`, or are both styles equally common? In terms of *pronunciation*, is it always `э́ный/э́ная/э́ное` (e.g., someone who writes n-я wouldn't actually say that as `э́ня`)?

EDIT: I found out later that for every variable `x` it's acceptable to express "*x-th*" as "*xтый*" (e.g., `m-ый = эмтый, n-ый = энтый, j-ый = житый, q-ый = кутый`), and since this works in all cases while the ending *-ный* for *n-ый* doesn't apply to variables ending with a vowel sound, I'll use the *-тый* version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While both written styles are grammatically correct, the more common one is

> n-ый, -ая, -ое, -ые

In addition, you could see sometimes the `n-` part spelled out in Russian as:

> энный, энная, энное, энные

The pronunciation in all cases would be

> э́нный / э́нная / э́нное / э́нные

(Note the double `н`)

pronunciation *э́ня* is wrong and it's more than likely that people will not understand what you're referring to.

Comment: +1 But what about энтый? Would you say it's incorrect? It is definitely common.

Comment: Aleks G, thanks! Is n-ый declined exactly like частный with the root эн in place of the root част?

Comment: @KCd Yes, declension is exactly as in частный

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan _энтый_ and its sibling-option _ентый_ are colloquial of _этот_ - quite a difference, I'd say.

Comment: Armen: related to your comment, I frequently heard in lectures the notation like a_i or x_i pronounced as "а итое" and "икс итое", or something close to that. A mathematician from St. Petersburg told me in *this particular setting* that is wrong and those should be "a и" and "икс и". But of course one might want to say i-th in some other situation. I'll add something about that to my question.

Comment: @AleksG: Obviously I mean энтый meaning n-ый, similar to итый, катый, etc. Do you mean to say that you've never heard something like энтый член последовательности?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Frankly, no, but I'm always willing to learn something new :) (and I went to a мехмат in Kharkiv University, although was good 20 years ago)

Comment: @AleksG: By the way, "n-th root" in the sense of algebra has to be translated as корень энной степени, never as энный корень, right?

Comment: @KCd That's correct.

Comment: @KCd That is correct.  Энный корень would refer to a root with sequential number N.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan : No, I have definitely never heard "энтый" instead of "энный". Probably a regional thing, i.e. not used in Moscow but the farther you go the more variations are expected to be found. Obviously, it is an inherited construction: if I always hear "i-тый", "k-тый", "n-ный" that's exactly what I am going to use if I become a professor myself. And then my students and so on. I still cringe when people use "проектировать" instead of "проецировать" even though it is technically correct — that's how strong the habit is.

Comment: @AleksG By the way, qworin is right. I checked it on gramota.ru : it is indeed recommended to use a shorter ending than some people do. Of course, the other way of spelling is also widespread, while not considered a good style.

Answer (score 3):

The grammatically correct form is only `n-й`.
Acoording to entrenched tradition accretion suffix must be one-letter if the last letter of numeral follows by vowel: `5-й день (пятый день)`, `25-я годовщина (двадцать пятая годовщина)`, `в 14-м ряду (в четырнадцатом ряду)`. It must be two-letter if the last letter of numeral follows by consonant: `5-го дня (пятого дня)`, `к 25-му студенту (к двадцать пятому студенту)`, `из 14-го ряда (из четырнадцатого ряда)`. Spelling `n-ый` is incorrect, but widely used. Sad but true; it is common mistake. Accretion suffixes for variables also comply these rules.

Comment: Thanks.  So if the last two letters are xy then you write n-y if x is vowel and -xy if x is a consonant.